# How to dismiss keyboad for ABNewPersonViewController when device rotates?

Tags: ios

ABNewPersonViewController is the system provided VC. So I assume I do not have direct access to its textFields/textViews dismiss keyboard.

- From my `RootViewController`, I push `AbNewPersonVC` as follows.
- When `AbNewPersonVC` is pushed, it presents keyboard
- Now I rotate the device to landscape.
- **Here I want to dismiss keyboard without dismissing the `AbNewPersonVC`**
- Then I present `LandscapeVC` on top of `AbNewPersonVC`
- When device rotates back to portrait, I dismiss `LandscapeVC`.
- **Here I want to re-present keyboard (dismissed above) for `AbNewPersonVC`**

Is it possible to do the same? If so, how?

```
ABNewPersonViewController *newPersonVC = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
[newPersonVC setNewPersonViewDelegate:self];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newPersonVC animated:YES];
```

I tried in viewWillTransitionToSize of the presentingVC. It does not help.

```
[newPersonVC.view endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: where you did try ?? this statement [newPersonVC.view endEditing:YES]; in Orientation delegate?? i think you should try with [self.view endEditing:YES];

Comment: Yes. in viewWillTransitionToSize of the presentingVC. The first statement. I also tried     [self.appDelegate.abNewPersonViewController resignFirstResponder];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not use system provided ABNewPersonViewController now. So, this issue does not exist for me anymore.

Answer (score 0):

1. in the ViewWillAppear of AbNewPersonVC, show your keypad
2. in the ViewWillDisappear of AbNewPersonVC dismiss your keypad